# How to broadcast-all in Akka?

Tags: akka, actor, broadcast

Java/Akka (v2.3.9) here. Each of my Akka `UntypedActor` subclasses has the ability to respond to several "*generic*" messages, such as `ExecuteOrder66`:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class StormTrooper extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if(message instanceof ExecuteOrder66) {
            // Betray the Jedi, serve only the emperor.
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I have 100 different actor subclasses that each support `ExecuteOrder66`. I need a way to [broadcast](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html) instances of this message to every single one of my actors; so like a public broadcast announce which *everybody* gets.

I think that link to the Akka docs above gets me close, but I'm not seeing one that sends an `ExecuteOrder66` to every single one of my actors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that it is not quite clear who "*everybody*" is. What if some actor `a` gets a handshake message from some other actor `b` from remote actor system, stores `b`'s reference, exchanges a few messages, then fails and restarts without the reference of `b`? Is `b` part of "everybody"? Who is responsible for finding the actor `b` again? How is one even supposed to know that `b` is still alive?

However, if you have a single specific actor system, a path selection with wildcards could do what you want. Something like this might do the job:

```
mySystem.actorSelection("akka://mySystemName/**")
```

This actor selection can then be used to `tell` (`!`) your broadcasted message to every actor on the system. You might also consider to be a little more restrictive, and select only the actors under `/user`, without touching the system actors.

Disclaimer: a little ad-hoc actor system I've just set up in the REPL doesn't complain about the path as indicated above, but I did not test it thoroughly. A runnable toy-example might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Tyukin (+1) - are you saying that Akka doesn't have the ability to "see" all the actors of a remote system? I would think that, at connection time (between two peer actor systems), there would be an exchange of information so that Actor System #1 running on `node1` could get real-time statistics/info about Actor System #2, perhaps running on `node2`. Are you saying this doesn't happen?!

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. But I can well imagine use cases where two actor systems `A` and `B` live more or less separately, and provide two completely different services on their own. From time to time, the system `A` might make a few requests to system `B`. `B` would just serve a request, and otherwise be quiet. Now if you have N different systems, they might also all be loosely coupled, and do their job more or less separately. Why would they want to exchange N real-time statistics all the time? Akka Cluster does something like this by default, but ordinary Actor Systems? I don't know.

Comment: A clarification to my previous comment: what you are saying (listing actors on other remote nodes, exchanging real-time stats etc) is of course *possible*, but it's not done by default. If there are two actor systems that are connected, I do not expect them to exchange tons of performance-stats all the time. In the same way, there is (afaik) no function for broadcasting something to the whole world, but it *can* be implemented quite easily, maybe by starting simple `MyBroadcaster` actors on each actor system.